# Is there a photo print provider I can use to offer a "Buy a print" feature on my own website?

Tags: printing, web, photo-galleries, online-shopping

I do host my own photo gallery online and want to share my photos with my community. It should be possible to purchase copies of my photos online. So I asked myself if there is a service provider for this situation. Best case: I can use a short javascript- or html-snippet that puts a "Buy a print" next to my photo.

Additional requirement (if possible at all): the service should be available in different languages (or language independent).

Before anyone asks: yes I googled a lot and asked all of my contacts.

**UPDATE**

I have tested:

1. RedBubble, but it is not what I am looking for. See my comment for details.
2. Fotomoto

   1. Nice an clean integration, with small problems
   2. No translation available
   3. Javascript is really hard to hook to customize certain things
   4. No support for offline testing (AFAICT)
   5. Payment only via credit card (which is no standard in many countries around the world)
3. Digibug

   1. (Sorry to say) It is ugly as hell
   2. Hard to admin
   3. Bad documentation
   4. No translation available

Comment: Never used any but the term you are looking for is *photographic print fulfillment*.

Comment: @Itai Thank you, but I am no native speaker so this is the first time I read those three words combined.

Comment: I am a native speaker and I think that's a clumsy phrase! IMO @eisberg has explained it clearly and that phrase would have been confusing.

Comment: What are you using to host your own photo gallery with?  I'm only asking since I also host my own photo gallery, but I use an open-source package for doing so called Gallery (http://gallery.menalto.com/), and I'm pretty sure there are extra Gallery modules that can be installed to do just what you're looking for (although I haven't used them myself).

Comment: @Conor Boyd I use my own PHP/MySQL based website build by myself. So as worst case I can emulate any type of gallery.

Comment: Yes, it a mouthful but if you [Google it](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=photographic+print+fulfillment), you'll get relevant results although none that satisfy the requirements in this question.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [FotoMoto](http://www.fotomoto.com/) as they integrate with a lot software and have an API for custom environments. Not sure on the language front though.

Comment: Thank you. This looks interesting. English only. But I will have a look in detail later. (+1)

Comment: FotoMoto seem to be a good option but I do not see a way to test my website setup offline. Any idea?

Comment: @eisberg - I haven't used them, but you might want to just ask them about that. I would be surprised if they didn't.

Answer (score 4):

[RedBubble](http://www.redbubble.com) is a great print provider that delivers worldwide and offers the kind of sales widget you're after for your own website:
[image]

Comment: I took a look at this. Am I wrong or do I really have to upload every photo myself? This would be impossible. I do have an existing website with 2500+ photos.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's correct. Sorry, I didn't realise you wanted to sell them without uploading them to the merchant. That does sound difficult!

Comment: That would be no problem if they have any web-service where my site can upload everything automatically. But anyway thanks for your answer, maybe someone else is looking for exactly this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a bit of coding, I can personally recommend [Pwinty](http://www.pwinty.com/). They have a simple RESTful API for ordering prints that you invoke from your site. You are responsible for billing etc. and they then invoice every month. This gives you complete control over everything and is very professional. Your prints can be shipped with your invoice and branding so that the customer never even knows you used a third party. I use pwinty for my site [OddPrints](http://www.oddprints.com/) which allows people to print at custom sizes. My site uses google wallet to handle billing and is open source so you can take a look at how I did it if you like!

If you want something simpler and cheaper (but with a lame user experience) you can also try [photobox pro galleries](http://www.photoboxgallery.com/). With this you just choose a markup over the photobox prices.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the Elite package from [Digibug.com](http://www.digibug.com/corp)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Shutterfly through the [Shutterfly API](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/start.sfly).

However, this may run into some of the same complaints you have with Fotomoto — credit cards required, for example — and, worse, if you have a Shutterfly account, you get promotions and deals almost every week, and those can't be applied to prints purchased in this way.

Also, in this case, all of the money goes to Shutterfly. You get nothing for your work in *making* the photo. That may be okay for some use, but probably isn't what you want if you consider your work to have any real value.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Peecho](http://www.peecho.com) they have what they call the [Simple Print Button](http://www.peecho.com/simple-print-button). It is a simple snippet of HTML which you can add to your site. This generates a Buy Print button and handles everything else, from selection products, shipping information, payment, customer support, printing and delivery. 
You can set a margin on each product to earn some profit.

There is also an API for more advanced integrations.

Answer (score 0):

Fotki offers prints at good prices with international delivery.

I'm in New Zealand and the prints have turned up promptly here when ordered.

www.fotki.com

Comment: They don't seem to offer the specific demands asked for in this question though, do they? That is, can you link to them from your own web site, without uploading your photos?